# How is the damage divided when using the Elemental Spell metamagic feat with Flame Strike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, metamagic

How is the damage divided when using the Elemental Spell metamagic feat with Flame Strike?

Elemental Spell says:

> Choose one energy type: acid, cold, electricity, or fire. You may
>   replace a spell’s normal damage with that energy type or split the
>   spell’s damage, so that half is of that energy type and half is of its
>   normal type.

Flame Strike's damage is divided:

> Half the damage is fire damage, but the other half results directly
>   from divine power

If Elemental Spell (cold) is applied at half cold, half fire, to Flame Strike, does the damage come out as 25% cold, 25% fire, 50% divine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 50% Cold, 25% Fire, 25% Divine

[Elemental Spell](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Elemental%20Spell):

> Choose one energy type: acid, cold, electricity, or fire. **You may replace a spell's normal damage with that energy type or split the spell's damage, so that half is of that energy type and half is of its normal type.** An elemental spell uses up a spell slot one level higher than the spell's actual level.

[Flame Strike](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Flame%20Strike):

> A flame strike evokes a vertical column of divine fire. **The spell deals 1d6 points of damage per caster level (maximum 15d6). Half the damage is fire damage, but the other half results directly from divine power and is therefore not subject to being reduced by resistance to fire-based attacks.**

Flame strike normally deals 50% fire and 50% divine damage. Looking at elemental spell we split the normal damage of Flame Strike with the type chosen by elemental spell, in this case cold.

This means the damage of the Flame strike can be broken down as such for the split damage usage of Elemental Spell:

- 50% Cold Damage
- 50% Normal spell damage

  - 50% Fire
  - 50% Divine

Which works out to be 50% Cold Damage, 25% Fire Damage, 25% Divine Damage.

---

Note: If you used the damage replacement option of Elemental spell, you'd deal 100% cold damage, not 50% Cold, 50% Divine.